# How can I typeset dialogue in the style of Shakespeares plays (Cambridge school)?

Tags: environments, quotation, dialogue

I want to create a centered environment as shown in the image below, with the speaker's name in caps lock, followed by the quote. The only thing I can think of is using amsmath (the \begin{align} environment) but this is designed for maths! I have to do \text{} every time if I try using that - I was looking for another package that may allow this style of typesetting more easily for English.

As an additional question (since there is no typography SE), why does Cambridge include gaps after the speakers name before starting the dialogue, example below. This doesn't occur all the time, and they don't really overlap. Note the gap after Wocester's name
[image]

Comment: This doesn't appear to be centered, just indented.  There are two places in this small sample where the dialogue is indented further than the rest. The first is after the long name “Worcester,” which is wider than the normal indentation.  The second is where one speaker begins a line of iambic pentameter, and the other finishes it.

Comment: That is, there seems to be both a minimum indent, and a minimum amount of space after each character’s name.

Comment: There are many packages for this, see https://www.ctan.org/topic/drama-script.

Comment: The question on the gap may be on topic on https://literature.stackexchange.com/, they have questions like https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/5493/why-does-my-copy-of-jude-the-obscure-use-part-first-instead-of-first-part, https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/15088/what-is-the-intention-and-purpose-behind-the-dash-style-book-format-compared-t, https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/8112/style-of-poetry-that-plays-with-typographic-rivers.

Comment: See https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/technica/examples